Self-created PDF-file with image as XObject leads to error 110 when Adobe-Acrobat is to open the file
n a self-created PDF-file (result of a small own PDF-creation-library in Java) I tried to place an RGB-Image with size 5x5 at location x=200, y=300.

When I open it with PDF XChange Editor (10.4.4), the image is not shown.
Opening with Acrobat Reader delivers an "Error: There was a problem reading this document (110)."

The attached PDF-file contains only one page with

the (intended) image as well as
a rectangle at the same coordinates (to be sure, that at least something is drawn).

For testing, the "Image" is created from the scratch by the above-mentioned library as an RGB-image (i.e., three components, red, green,blue) with 8 bits component (i.e. one byte) per sample (I think, this is the term, Adobe uses for "point" in this context).
In the PDF-File, each of the samples are represented by 3 bytes with values "0FF", "000", "000" in successive order (see line 95 in the definition of the XObject /XO01 as object number 11). That makes 5x5x3=75 bytes.
As said, PDF-XChange Edituro refuses to show the image and Acrobat Reader claims an error.
Even though I have double-checked several times (object locations, literal names, syntax) I must admit that I do not see the error (which is obviously present!).
QUESTION:
Do you have any hint what is wrong within the PDF?
ADDITIONAL NOTES

My (currently single) source of information is
[PDFSPEC]

I have attached the complete PDF-File since I am afraid of cutting important things, in case I would extract only the XObject-section. I hope, this is OK.

The /ProcSet still contains /Text, since usually there is also some Text in the PDF file. However,

Deleting /Text does not change the behaviors (and as sec. 14.2 of [PDFSPEC] mentions, it is obsolete beginning with PDF1.4)

The defined Font is unused, the PDF-ID is meaningless, as well as the PDF-Info-section.

The mentioned Image name "ATH_TEST-PNG-01-241216a.png" is useless at the moment. Once the handling of images works for me, this will represent the name of an embedded PNG-file (will come from a BufferedImage in java, but is not part of the problem)

There is no FIlter declare in order to see the bytes as they are

I hope, that the error was not too stupid!


%PDF-1.5
%–—˜™%
%  PROGRAM  : ---
%  FILE     : D:NNNNNNNNNN\ath_jrt_iopdf_testfile.pdf
%  TITLE    : ---
%  PURPOSE  : ---
%  AUTHOR   : ---
%  CONTACT  : ---
%  COMPANY  : ---
%  CREATION : 20241225-062506Z(+000)
%  DATE     : 20241225-062506Z(+000)
%  COMMENT  : ---
%  INFO     : ---
%
1 0 obj
<<
/Title (---)
/Author (---)
/Subject (---)
/Keywords (---)
/Creator (---)
/CreationDate D:20241225064506
/ModDate D:20241225064506
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Version 1.4
/Pages 6 0 R
/PageLayout /SinglePage
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 6 0 R
/MediaBox [ 0 0 595 842]
/Contents 4 0 R
/Rotate 0.0
/Resources
<<
/ProcSet [  /PDF /Text /ImageC ]
/Font
<<
/F01 7 0 R
>>
/XObject
<<
/XO01 8 0 R
>>
>>
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/Length 5 0 R
>>
stream
 200.000000 300.000000 5.000000 5.000000 re S  q  1.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 1.000000 200.000000 300.000000 cm  1.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 cm  /XO01 Do Q 
endstream
endobj
5 0 obj
184
endobj
6 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Kids [
3 0 R
]
/Count 1
>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<<
/Type /Font
/Subtype /Type1
/BaseFont /Helvetica
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
>>
endobj
8 0 obj
<<
/Length 9 0 R
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Name ATH_TEST-PNG-01-241216a.png
/Width 5
/Height 5
/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB
/BitsPerComponent 8
>>
stream
ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  ÿ  endstream
endobj
9 0 obj
75
endobj
xref
0 10
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000290 00000 n 
0000000441 00000 n 
0000000527 00000 n 
0000000727 00000 n 
0000000963 00000 n 
0000000982 00000 n 
0000001041 00000 n 
0000001138 00000 n 
0000001392 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/Size 10
/Root 2 0 R
/Info 1 0 R
/ID
[
(01010101ABABAB)(01010101ABABAB)]
>>
startxref
1410
%%EOF



Well.... The first problem is that PDF is a binary format, and CR/LF matter. The listing above assumes LF terminators (for the startxref to be correct), but actually, on my PC anyway, contains CR/LF pairs, making the startxref incorrect (and making the length of the xref entries not exactly 20 bytes). The CreationDate and ModDate are given without parentheses to denote string objects. The same problem for the /Name in the image dictionary, it needs () round the name. If I fix all those Acrobat displays the file.

Hi Ken,
I just rechecked the original pdf-File in notepad++ with all "symbols" (in german the menu option is called "Ale Symbole anzeigen") to be shown. EOLs are definitely only LFs and the positions of the objects were checked (I wonder whther CRs were added during copy&past!?). Thank's for the note concerning the dates, I will correct this.
Concenring the xref: The "n"  ist always at column 18 (counting from "1"), then one SPACE and then the LF. That equals to 20. And here we are: the () around the name were the problem! So many thanks!!!! Problem solved!

As a consequence, could you please share the PDF in a binary-friendly way, like putting it up on a file share platform (that doesn't drown us in ads) and paying the link here?

Do I need to close this topic? I will check for an stackoverflow-howto!

I just tried DropBox. I hope that this works:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/v3y5z8yuwk3isrykbtci5/ath_jrt_iopdf_testfile_241225b.pdf?rlkey=onrscnsyya9zfb67mqkfun0c5&st=yb7p1cr8&dl=0

There are several ways to self write a PDF in "old school" ASCII or ANSI (as long as you avoid and or work your programming around the problem areas).
As far as I can tell your PDF is a working program output just the image definition is not quite right. All your pixels look like they are in one default pixel square.


Programmable MS Notepad, command line VBScript or console CMD are all possible, but less so for more complex methods (AFAIK unsuited to signing), but perhaps never say impossible. Certainly Form Fields should not be an issue. Command lines can build a text.PDF and then concatenate imbedded Binary Rich Media such as Movies and 3D.
This is a minimal 3x3 but could just as easily be 5 x 5 the most difficult  bits are the alpha transparency to show bottom left black pixel is now fully transparent thus seen as no colour on white.

https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/raw/master/coloursAscii.pdf
The points to note are the pixels are set as the 3 lines of pixels as one nominal inch as there are no native DPI in a PDF. (3 dpi is meaningless in a unitless file)
%PDF-1.7
%‰«Íï
1 0 obj <</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>> endobj
2 0 obj <</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[3 0 R]>> endobj
3 0 obj <</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 72 72]/Rotate 0/Resources 4 0 R/Contents 6 0 R/Parent 2 0 R>> endobj
4 0 obj <</XObject<</Img3 7 0 R>>>> endobj
5 0 obj <</Length 9/Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width 3/Height 3/BitsPerComponent 1/ColorSpace/DeviceGray/Filter/ASCIIHexDecode>>
stream
ffff7fff>
endstream
endobj
6 0 obj <</Length 46>>
stream
1 0 0 -1 -0 72 cm
72 0 0 -72 0 72 cm
/Img3 Do

endstream
endobj
7 0 obj <</Length 55/Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width 3/Height 3/BitsPerComponent 8/SMask 5 0 R/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Filter/ASCIIHexDecode>>
stream
ff000000ff000000ff00ffffff00ffffff00000000ffffff000000>
endstream
endobj

xref
0 8
0000000000 00002 f
0000000016 00000 n
0000000062 00000 n
0000000114 00000 n
0000000218 00000 n
0000000262 00000 n
0000000426 00000 n
0000000521 00000 n

trailer
<</Size 8/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
743
%%EOF


Answer
In the case of the 25 red pixels. The problem is they seem to not be programmed to spread out in the square but are all in bottom left corner. If we alter a few from red to blue and green, we can see they are all there, but in a default unitary rectangle.

You can thus either:
Use just one pixel and define it's placement width and height to be 5 times bigger.
OR
Define all 25 pixels to be the same height and width as the rectangle.  this can be that result if 5 units wide by high by changing
1.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 cm to 5 0 0 5 0 0 cm

OR
Fill the rectangle with red.

The problem was finally solved:

There was a missing pair of (round) brackets to identify the Name of the image as a string (line 88)
The other relevant mistake was on line 60: I expected that the scaling of the CTM scales the number of pixels to a PDF-width. Instead, the "scaling" (parameters "a" and "d") actually provide the width and height for themselves.

After changing

/Name ATH_TEST-PNG-01-241216a.png (line 88) to /Name (ATH_TEST-PNG-01-241216a.p) (for deomonstration purposes I just stripped the "n" from "png" to keep the xref-positions untouched) and
1.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 1.000000 200.000000 300.000000 cm (line 60) to 100.0000 0.000000 -0.000000 100.0000 200.000000 300.000000 cm (this coincides with KJs final statement in his answer.

As consequence the result was as expected: The PDF-viewers show the red test-image inside (more precisely: "above" the outlining blac rectangle (of linewidth 1pt)) ).
The problem was solved by KenS initial comment: Many thanks to all comments and answers!

Actually there are more entries that are wrong: in the Info dictionary the dates also are missing their brackets. In the Catalog the version is not a name. And while not invalid, I assume you meant the ID parts to be a hex strings, not a verbatim one.

Thank you. That was changed in between in the creating library. Also, KenS mentioned, that the /Mane key in the XObject directory has to be a name-Object instead of a string object. This is also changed. I can conclude, that due to the comments in Stackoverflow I could finish my small pdf-creating library (I did not want dto use third-party code). I hope, that one day I will be able to contribute to the community
